# Column Named Cannot be Found

Tags: c#, mysql

I have 2 datagrid that needs to show data from 2 tables, I used 2 load table for each datagrid to show the data.

```
public diagnosechipcomplainprint()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    load_table();
}

void load_table()
{
    string query = "Select HospitalRecordNo,concat(Patient_Fname, ' ', Patient_Mname, ' ',Patient_Lname) as 'Patient Name',Age,Gender,DateOfBirth,Email,PatientContact from patientinfo;";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sd = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sd.SelectCommand = com;
        DataTable dba = new DataTable();
        sd.Fill(dba);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dba;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        sd.Update(dba);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

void load_table2()
{
    string query2 = "Select VisitNo, HospitalRecordNo, DateOfVisit from visit_details where HospitalRecordNo = '" + recordno.Text + "';";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(query2, con);

    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter sd = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sd.SelectCommand = com;
        DataTable dba = new DataTable();
        sd.Fill(dba);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dba;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = bs;
        sd.Update(dba);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And when i do cell click on the first data grid the data from datagrid will show in label, but when i click on the second data grid it shows error.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        recordno.Text = 
        row.Cells["HospitalRecordNo"].Value.ToString();
        pname.Text = row.Cells["Patient Name"].Value.ToString();
        age.Text = row.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString();
        gender.Text = row.Cells["Gender"].Value.ToString();
        dateofbirth.Text = row.Cells["DateOfBirth"].Value.ToString();
        email.Text = row.Cells["Email"].Value.ToString();
        contact.Text = row.Cells["PatientContact"].Value.ToString();
    }
}

private void dataGridView2_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row1 = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        visitno.Text = row1.Cells["VisitNo"].Value.ToString();
        rec.Text = row1.Cells["HospitalRecordNo"].Value.ToString();
        dateofvisit.Text = row1.Cells["DateOfVisit"].Value.ToString();
        nurse.Text = row1.Cells["Nurse_on_duty"].Value.ToString();
        temp.Text = row1.Cells["Temperature"].Value.ToString();
        cardiac.Text = row1.Cells["Cardiac_Rate"].Value.ToString();
        respiratory.Text = 
        row1.Cells["Respiratory_Rate"].Value.ToString();
        bloodpress.Text = 
        row1.Cells["Blood_Pressure"].Value.ToString();
        weight.Text = row1.Cells["Weight"].Value.ToString();
        sat.Text = row1.Cells["02_Stat"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

That is the code i used in Cellclick datagrid view 2.
I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: In which line the exception thrown? Make sure that all column names mentioned in `row1.Cells["ColumnName"]` exists.

Comment: What 's error which was thrown? If there are exceptions, you should post the stack trace also.  Then we can analyse it easier.

Comment: `nurse.Text = row1.Cells["Nurse_on_duty"].Value.ToString();` Your query doesn't return that column.

Comment: The second query only returns 3 columns: `VisitNo`, `HospitalRecordNo` and `DateOfVisit`. Other additional columns afterwards indicated by `row1.Cells` key indexer are not available in result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that query for second `DataGridView` only contains 3 column definitions, which actually you need 10 columns as mentioned in `DataGridViewRow.Cells` indexer:

```
// only 3 columns returned in result set
string query2 = "Select VisitNo, HospitalRecordNo, DateOfVisit from visit_details where HospitalRecordNo = '" + recordno.Text + "';";
```

You should mention all column names required by `DataGridViewRow.Cells` in query result set, with [parameterized query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) to prevent SQL injection:

```
string query2 = @"Select VisitNo, HospitalRecordNo, DateOfVisit, Nurse_on_duty, 
                  Temperature, Cardiac_Rate, Respiratory_Rate, Blood_Pressure, 
                  Weight, 02_Stat
                  from visit_details where HospitalRecordNo = @RecordNo";

// MySqlCommand parameter assignment
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordNo", recordno.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error at runtime since your query does not return a column called `Nurse_on_duty`. *The same issue is occurring with some of the other columns also.*

```
nurse.Text = row1.Cells["Nurse_on_duty"].Value.ToString();
```